# Смена классов только у элемента, на который наведён курсор

Tags: jquery

Имеется список элементов, который формируется динамически из базы:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list">Один</li>
    <li class="list">Два</li>
    <li class="list">Три</li>
</ul>
```

Далее на каждый элемент навешивается обработчик события:

```
$('.list').mouseover(function() {
    $('.list').removeClass('invisible');
    $('.list').addClass('visible');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('.list').removeClass('visible');
    $('.list').addClass('invisible');
});
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении эта функция срабатывала именно для элемента, на который наведен курсор?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `this` в обработчиках `mouseover` и `mouseout`. Эта переменная указывает на текущий элемент, для которого сработал обработчик:

```
$('.list').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('invisible')
        .addClass('visible');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('visible')
        .addClass('invisible');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это то, что нужно

Comment: @ZaurK, если я полностью ответил на ваш вопрос, отметьте его как "принятый" (галочка слева от вопроса)